# JavaScript objects with resetting variables

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm just learning JavaScript Objects and have a question/problem. I have the following code / js object:

**CHANGED: This is the complete code - it's a Appcelerator Titanium Project!:**

```
spike.xhr = spike.xhr || {};

spike.xhr.init = function() {
    this.severResponse = '';
    this.xhrMethod = 'GET';
}

spike.xhr.isOnline = function() {
    if( Titanium.Network.online ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

spike.xhr.notOnline = function() {
    var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({ 
        title: CONFIG.PROJECT_SHORT, 
        message: 'You do not have an online connect. Please connect...',
        buttonNames: ['Continue'],
        cancel: 0
    }); 
    alertDialog.show(); 
}

spike.xhr.connect = function( url ) {

    if( spike.xhr.isOnline() ) {
        spike.xhr.clients = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

        spike.xhr.clients.onload = function() {
            if (spike.xhr.clients.status != 200 && spike.xhr.clients.status != 201) {
                var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({ 
                    title: CONFIG.PROJECT_SHORT, 
                    message: 'We are sorry, but we have received an status error!',
                    buttonNames: ['Continue'],
                    cancel: 0
                }); 
                alertDialog.show(); 
                return false;
            }    
            this.serverResponse = this.responseText; 
        }

        spike.xhr.clients.onerror = function(e) {
            Ti.API.log( 'ERROR: ' + e.status + ': ' + e.statusText + ' - ' + e.error );
        }   

        spike.xhr.clients.open( this.xhrMethod, url );

        spike.xhr.clients.send();
    } else {
        spike.xhr.notOnline();
    }
}

spike.xhr.basicAuthentication = function( username, password ) {
    authstr = 'Basic ' +Titanium.Utils.base64encode( username+':'+ password);
    spike.xhr.client.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', authstr );
}

spike.xhr.setMethod = function( type ) {
    this.xhrMethod = type;
}

spike.xhr.response = function() {
    return this.serverResponse;
}
```

If I now run:

```
spike.xhr.connect( 'http://mydomain' );
theResponse = spike.xhr.response();
```

I get `<null>` returned! - why do I not get `"This is a Test!"` back or better question:
What do I have to change to get `"This is a Test!"` back?

Comment: Is XHR some kind of XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) ?

Comment: please provide the code of `spike.xhr.connect` function - probably you're looking for returned value while an ajax call is still running

Comment: The thing is, when i add an alert(this.serverRepsonse) below this.serverResponse = "This is a test!", i correctly get "This is a test!"?!?!?

Comment: @StanleyStuart: yes, it should be an object to handle xhr requests.

Comment: The line containing spike.xhr.response() is executed _before_ the value is changed, likely because an asynchronous call is being made in the connect-function.

Comment: When someone takes the time to remove meaningless verbiage, like **Hey Guys**, please do not add it back in. Also, please use proper grammar in your posts by capitalizing the letter `I` when used as a first person pronoun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the above code doesn't work is because your `spike.xhr.connect` function is *asynchronous*.  This means you can tell the browser to make a request, but continue doing other stuff while the browser waits for the response to come back.

JavaScript runs in a single thread, meaning that you can only execute one thing at a time.  Certain operations like "AJAX" calls are *asynchronous* in that the browser knows how to make that request, but doesn't block your currently running code to wait for the request.  Typically, asynchronous code is called with a *callback function*, which runs *when the request is returned*:

```
// pseudo code.

spike.xhr.connect( 'http://google.com', function ( response ) {
    alert( 'google' );
});
alert( 'this will fire before spike.xhr.connects callback' );
```

The callback function will be executed when the response from the server comes back *AND* the browser *isn't doing anything else*.

Comment: It looks like spike.xhr.clients.onload is intended as a callback but it doesn't invoke a passed-in callback such as Stanley Stuart is suggesting.  With his suggestion, invoke that 2nd parameter as a function within spike.xhr.clients.onload.